# How to sum the elements of hash?

Tags: perl, data-structures

Hi I have a hash where the key is a 3digit code and value is number of elements under that code. I want to sum the 3digit code and multiply with the number of elements, then finally add them up. Example:

```
000 23
012 42
222 34

[(0+0+0)*23]+[(0+1+2)*42]+[(2+2+2)*34]=0+126+204=330
```

so i tried

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash ){      
@arrSum=split(//, $key);
   foreach $i (@arrSum){    
     $sum+=$i;
     $value=$sum*$hash{$key};
   }    
}
```

It does not work. It actually has to consider each line, instead it sums up all the 3digit code at once. Need some help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is more [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach to the problem, it also uses `sum` from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util):

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

my %hash = qw(
    000 23
    012 42
    222 34
);

print sum(map { sum(split //) * $hash{$_} } keys %hash);     # 330
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a small change in your code, and I got the right value:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
   "000" => 23,
   "012" => 42,
   "222" => 34,
);

my $value = 0;
for my $key (sort keys %hash )
{  
   my $sum = 0;
   my @arrSum = split(//, $key);
   for my $i (@arrSum)
   {    
     $sum += $i;
   }
   $value += $sum * $hash{$key};
}

print "$value\n";
```

Comment: sorting the keys of the hash seem completely unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

(a+b+c)*d = (a*d)+(b*d)+(c*d), so you could do

```
my $value;
for my $key (keys %hash) {      
   for my $digit (split(//, $key)) {
      $value += $digit * $hash{$key};
   }    
}
```

But it looks like you were trying for:

```
my $value;
for my $key (keys %hash) {      
   my $sum;
   $sum += $_ for split(//, $key);
   $value += $sum * $hash{$key};
}
```

More or less the same:

```
use List::Util qw( sum );

my $value;
for my $key (keys %hash) {      
   $value += sum(split(//, $key)) * $hash{$key};
}
```

Comment: sum(split(//, $key)))
Isn't there an extra parenthesis?

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, It's now gone.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems tailor-made for [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use List::Util qw( sum );

my %hash = (
   "000" => 23,
   "012" => 42,
   "222" => 34,
);

my $total;
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %hash ) {
    $total += sum(split //, $key) * $val;
}

print "$total\n";
```